# Composer loading libs depending on configuration

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a PHP script that uploads some files to the cloud. Depending on the configuration it can handle upload to `AWS` or `Azure`. Now, this requires two rather big SDKs but at the build time I already know which of these clouds is required.

Is there any nice way to modify `composer install/update` so that it wouldn't download both SDK?

Comment: purpose being to save on disk space on the running instance ?

Comment: That's for utility for taking database dump, cleaning it up for GDPR compatibility so that it can be used on test/staging environments. Depending on customer we need to use different cloud providers for storing such files so we know for certain which SDK is needed in particular setup...

Comment: Then I would not do that. Just keep both on your running instances. If you properly setup composer and you require the `autoload.php` module very early in the setup. only the classes needed will ever be loaded at runtime.  The only 'cost' is the extra disk space for both libraries, but again : not a runtime consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Just to write a bash script to install needed version of your composer.json file:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
if [[ "$1" == "sdk-1" ]]; then
    COMPOSER=sdk-1.composer.json /usr/local/bin/composer install
else
    COMPOSER=sdk-2.composer.json /usr/local/bin/composer install
fi
```

Then you can install needed sdk like this:

```sh
./your_script.sh sdk-1
```

Also, you can to put your second SDK to require-dev section of your composer.json file.
And install with/without dev packages:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
if [[ "$1" == "--no-dev" ]]; then
    /usr/local/bin/composer install --no-dev
else
    /usr/local/bin/composer install
fi
```

Then:

```sh
./your_script.sh --no-dev
```